# Correção de coordenadas de imagem no MATLAB

Tags: imagem, matlab, coordenadas

[image: Imagem de entrada]Bom dia, sou iniciante no uso do *MATLAB* e acredito que esteja tendo problemas com questões simples mas uma pequena ajuda seria uma grande contribuição.

Estou tentando realizar a correção de coordenadas de uma imagem de tamanho 2048x2048.

Como quero que o centro da minha imagem esteja localizado na origem dos eixos usei os seguintes comandos:

```
Ii=imread('PVCgrid.tif');
figure; imshow(Ii)


DFD = 265;
R = 205;
P = 0.2;



[L,C]=size(Ii);


[yi,xi] =  meshgrid(-(L-1)/2:(L-1)/2,-(C-1)/2:(C-1)/2);%(pixels)


[Y,X] = meshgrid(1:L,1:C);%(pixels)


yc = yi.*0.2;%(mm)
xc = xi.*0.2;%(mm)
% transforma as unidades das coordenadas de pixel para mm



a = (yc.^2) + (DFD^2)+(xc.^2);%(mm)
b = 2*(-(DFD^2)+(R*DFD));%(mm)
c = ((DFD^2) - (2*R*DFD));%(mm)


delta = b^2 - ((4.*a) * c);
denominador = 2 .* a;
numerador_1 = -(b) + sqrt(delta);
numerador_2 = -(b) - sqrt(delta);

t_1 = numerador_1 ./ denominador;

%Determina o fator de correção

u1 =(yc.*t_1);
v1 =(xc.*t_1);
% Aplica a correção

u =u1./P;
v =v1./P;
% Retorna para a unidade original


tmap_B = cat(3,u_transl,v_transl);

resamp = makeresampler('linear','fill');

Io = tformarray(Ii,[],resamp,[2 1],[1 2],[],tmap_B,1);

imwrite(Io,'gridcorrigida.tif','tif')

figure; imshow(Io)
```

Já refiz a matemática mais de uma vez mas ao aplicar a correção estou tendo o resultado inverso do esperado, as bordas se esticam quando deveriam ser comprimidas, alguém teria alguma ideia de onde estou errando?

Obrigado!

Comment: Numa vista rapida no código, não encontrei nada de anormal. Vc teria como colocar a imagem para fazer um teste do output?

Comment: sim @Guto, sem problema.

Comment: Obrigado, assim que sobrar um tempo vou dar uma olhada :D !